# Double clicking modifier causes scrolling in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, resharper

I have a strange quirk going on and hopefully someone knows the setting that I need to turn it off. I have the latest Visual Studio 2017 and Resharper.

Given this method signature

```
public void Foo()
```

I double click on `void` to highlight it. The code editor jumps that line to the bottom of the window. It only appears to happen after I jump using Resharper's Find Usages to something in the method.

For example:

```
// ...
public void Foo()
// ...
== Bottom of Window ==
```

becomes:

```
// ...
public void Foo()
== Bottom of Window ==
```

How do I get it to keep it from scrolling? Seems like a bug or preference somewhere.

Comment: just tried mine works alright with resharper find usages. Though i have tried with scroll lock on/off, you might wanna give a chance to toggle your scroll lock ?